# Emit objects for drawing in the UI in a regular interval using RxJava on Android

Tags: android, rx-java

I am parsing SVG files in an Observable. Points are emitted as "Path" object as the XML is parsed. Parsing happens in a separate thread and I want to draw the SVG file point by point. In other words, I want to emit the points to the UI one by one, for example one every 50 msec.

```
private void drawPath(final String chars) {

    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Path>() {

        @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Path> subscriber) {
            try {

                while ([omitted]) {

                    // omitted: a lot of processing
                    // an XML path from an SVG file is parsed into an Android path to be drawn on a canvas
                    // this happens point by point

                    subscriber.onNext(path); // emit path point by point as the XML is processed
                }
            }
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }

    }).buffer(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 1) // delay each point so the UI can process it and is not overwhelmed
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<List<Path>>() {

                @Override public void call(List<Path> paths) {
                    System.out.println("**** SVG Parser: drawPath on UI thread");

                    if (paths.size() > 0) { drawPath(paths.get(0), paint); }

                }

            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {

                @Override public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace(); // ignore silently
                }

            });

}
```

When I use .buffer() as shown, each Path is emitted as soon as it is produced. The .buffer() seems not to do anything here.

I have tried to .throttle(), but then points are omitted.

How can I make this work?

BTW: There is no backpressure issue here as the SVG file which is parsed is finite. I only want to parse it in a separate thread, buffer the results and emit them slowly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `.zip()` operator with a `.timer()`. From original RxJava wiki:

- **[zip()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#zip)**:

  > combine Observables together via a specified function and emit items
  >   based on the results of this function
- **[timer()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#timer)**:

  > create an Observable that emits a single item after a given delay

So, if you use `zip()` to combine your original `Observer` with `timer()`, you can delay the output of each `Path` every 50 msecs:

```
private void drawPath(final String chars) {
    Observable.zip(
        Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Path>() {
            // all the drawing stuff here
            ...
        }),
        Observable.timer(0, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
        new Func2<Path, Long, Path>() {
            @Override
            public Path call(Path path, Long aLong) {
                return path;
            }
        }
    )
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    ...
}
```

Comment: public Path call(Path path, Long aLong) has a syntax error as it seems, and context help is telling me I need Spanned as the return argument: public Spanned call(SVGPath path, Long aLong). When I place drawPath() inside this call, it is still raised immediately, so I assume I must attach .subscribe() after observeOn(), but then how would I get the path there?

Comment: I don't know where my previous comment is gone, but here we go again: the code I put in my answer at the beginning had a typo (Spanned is part of a snippet I had locally, and has to be considered a typo). Nevertheless the code in the answer has been fixed and some more reference provided.