# Why does this observable emit only one value

Tags: android, rx-java

I have the following code based on an example provided by @a.bertucci here [Emit objects for drawing in the UI in a regular interval using RxJava on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206805/emit-objects-for-drawing-in-the-ui-in-a-regular-interval-using-rxjava-on-android), where I zip an Observable with a Timer. When I trigger the subscription by calling processDelayedItems(), the code [A] in the zipped Observable is executed exactly once and one item is emitted to [B]. I would have expected code [A] to run continuously once triggered and keep emitting items every 1500 msec, but it obviously only runs once here.

```
private static void processDelayedItems() {

    Observable.zip(
            Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {

                @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
                    // [A] this code is only called once
                    subscriber.OnNext(o)
                }

            }),
            Observable.timer(1500, 1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), new Func2<Object, Long, Object>() {
                @Override public Object call(Object entity, Long aLong) {
                    return entity;
                }
            }
    )
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {

                @Override public void call(Object entity) {
                    // ... and accordingly one item is emitted [B]
                }

            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {

                @Override public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }

            }, new Action0() {

                @Override public void call() {

                }

            });

}
```

1. Can anybody see the problem which I have here? Is it that I need to reference the Observable from outside the function to keep it alive for more time? Is it collected by GC (Android)? Is it a problem that the function is static?
2. What are the rules for Observables in terms of their livetime? Are there any best practices how longer-running Observables should be referenced and if they can be static at all? In my tests I noticed that it doesn't really matter, but maybe it does here, when a timer is involved.

--

Corrected code [not working yet]:

- added repeat()

  ```
  Observable.zip(
          Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {

              @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
                  // [A] this code is only called once
                  subscriber.OnNext(o);
                  subscriber.OnCompleted();
              }

          }).repeat(Schedulers.newThread()),
          Observable.timer(1500, 1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), new Func2<Object, Long, Object>() {
              @Override public Object call(Object entity, Long aLong) {
                  return entity;
              }
          }
  )
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {

              @Override public void call(Object entity) {
                  // ... and accordingly one item is emitted [B]
              }

          }, new Action1<Throwable>() {

              @Override public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                  throwable.printStackTrace();
              }

          }, new Action0() {

              @Override public void call() {

              }

          });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need `repeat` to generate an infinite Observable. E.g.,

```
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {

        @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
            // [A] this code is only called once
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext(o);
            }
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }

    }).repeat(Schedulers.newThread());
```

> Is it that I need to reference the Observable from outside the function to keep it alive for more time? Is it collected by GC (Android)? Is it a problem that the function is static?

Since you use `Schedulers.newThread()` and `timer`, there will be some other Threads which has a reference to your Observable. You don't need more work.

> What are the rules for Observables in terms of their livetime? Are there any best practices how longer-running Observables should be referenced and if they can be static at all? In my tests I noticed that it doesn't really matter, but maybe it does here, when a timer is involved.

You're right. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. This makes sense because the Y combinator looks for observables on both sides and if there is nothing to zip on one side, then nothing is emitted.

Comment: I just tested and - no idea why - the Observable still emits only once. My corrected code is above below my original post. Even though I don't think so please check if I have added repeat() to the correct Observable.

Comment: Another question: Is there a way to achieve the same differently? Like instead of using zip, having a timer/interval Observable emit regular intervals, which then trigger another Observable switched serially behind the timer/interval Oberservable?

Comment: You forgot to add `subscriber.onCompleted();` after your `subscriber.onNext(o);`.  `Repeat` cannot start repeating if the original `Observable` doesn't complete first.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that you had this there, but I didn't realize that I must call OnCompleted() to be able to start the Observable again. After I call OnCompleted() the Observable emits regularly, but it doesn't respect the timer anymore, e.g. if emits as fast as it can. I have updated my code above.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the Observable from emitting items? The Observable pulls from a queue and when that queue is empty, it must stop itself. Normally I would call OnCompleted() when the Observable realizes there is nothing more to emit and it stops itself. Now, as I must call OnCompleted() after each emitted item, there is no way for the Observable to stop itself.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to your comment, for simplicity you could do this,

```
Observable.timer(1500, 1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Object> call(Long aLong) {
                String o = "0";
                return Observable.from(o);
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object aLong) {
                System.out.println(aLong);
            }
        });
```

Here you still get the benefits of the timer without the added zip / repeat on top.  It's still a bit verbose but it's a bit simpler.

Comment: This looks much better. When I use Observable.from(o); where o is of type Object, it tells me "from" is depreciated. So I changed it to Observable.from(new Object[] { entity }); - just in case anybody reads this.

Comment: Use `just` instead of the deprecated `from`.

Comment: @Miguel Lavigne, why not a `map`?

Comment: @zsxwing, I used flatMap because the question what using an Observable as the entry point for is data, Observable<Object>.  I made no assumption on how that Observable was being used.  With flatMap he could get that Observable from another class if he wanted.  On the other hand if the Object is returned inline then map would work as well.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for the two solutions. I went with this here and it does what I need to do. I still don't understand why the other solution does not work properly, but it might have had to do with an implementation detail. - I did not mark any as correct, as this here works for me, but the other is closer to my original question.